# Images Moving Onto Next Line But Text Is Not

Tags: html, css

I have two different sections with exactly the same CSS code but if you look at the image below, you can see at the width the screen is set to, that the images are all already moved onto a new line (which is what I want) but the categories underneath are still on the same line and get more "squashed" together. How can I make it so the categories move onto a new line like the images do? Thanks in advance.

Image of problem - http://i.imgur.com/u6GnTa1.png

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lakeside Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
    <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <h3 id="welcometext">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" ...Search Book Title" class="searchstyle"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #333">
                    <a href="1Index.html" class="link">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="2Catgeories.html" class="link">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Find Us
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionone">
        <div id="containerone">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>LAKESIDE BOOKS</h1>
                    <p>KERRYS LOCAL BOOKSTORE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sectiontwo">
        <div id="containertwo">
            <h2 class="sectionhead">Best Selling Books</h2>
                <div id="bestsellerimages">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/4.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>The Girl On The Train <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Paula Hawkins</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/3.jpg" alt="book2" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>Meet Me In Manhattan <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Claudia Carroll</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/5.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>The Pointless Book 2 <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Alfie Deyes</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            <h3 class="secfooter">Mere Bestsellers <span style="color: #ed786a;"><strong>Here</strong></span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionthree">
        <div id="containerthree">
            <h2 class="sectionhead">Popular Categories</h2>
                <div class="categories">
                    <h3>Fiction</h3>
                    <p>New Releases</p>
                    <p>Australian Fiction</p>
                    <p>Crime & Mystery</p>
                    <p>Childrens</p>
                    <p>Fantasy</p>
                </div>

                <div class="categories">
                    <h3>Fiction</h3>
                    <p>New Releases</p>
                    <p>Australian Fiction</p>
                    <p>Crime & Mystery</p>
                    <p>Childrens</p>
                    <p>Fantasy</p>
                </div>

                <div class="categories">
                    <h3>Fiction</h3>
                    <p>New Releases</p>
                    <p>Australian Fiction</p>
                    <p>Crime & Mystery</p>
                    <p>Childrens</p>
                    <p>Fantasy</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { /* ### */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Arial, "Open Sans", sans-serif-light, sans-serif, "Segoe UI";
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#nav {
    color: #DADADA;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover {
    background:#333;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.link {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#welcometext {
    text-align: center;
    /*font-style: italic;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#searchbar {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: right;
}
#searchbar .searchstyle{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#searchbar input {
    max-width: 95%;
}
#sectionone {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
}
#containerone {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
}
#header {
    margin: 6em 0 6em 0;
}
#logo h1 {
    color: #ed786a;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
#logo p {
    margin-top: -0.6em;
    color: #888888;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
#sectiontwo {
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#containertwo {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888888;
    padding: 0 0 2em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
}
.sectionhead{
    margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
    color: #888888;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#bestsellerimages{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
#bestsellerimages img{
    padding: 0;
}
#bestsellerimages figure{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 131px;
}
#bestsellerimages figcaption{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#bestsellerimages figure .imgbot{
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
#sectionthree {
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#containerthree {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888888;
    padding: 0 0 2em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
}
.secfooter{
    color: #888888;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
.categories{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your categories divs are set to width: 20% with display: inline-block causing them to remain in columns. First, if you want them to stack on top of each other you either change the width to 100% and/or display to block:

```
.categories{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will affect the design on desktop so if you're building this responsively you would actually just add:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .categories{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That aligns the categories one under another which I only want happening one the size of the screen is being reduced. So what I mean is as you reduce the size of the window they will reduce one after another.

Comment: It works, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGxOdJ I've just set it to 568px for the media query. You can increase it if you need.